# Swift: Reopen app from background, willEnterForeground runs before appdelegate

Tags: ios, swift

If my app is put to the background (someone clicks the home button), and then reopens, I want to run a a function in my ViewController, and I have been able to get this using the willEnterForeground() function but I need the url that has been opened inside my app (so say I am in Mail, I open a PDF and I say to open that pdf in my app), and to get that I use the func application I pasted below which works, however, the willEnterForeground function runs before the application func and I will run the method I want before I get the url. Is there a way I can somehow can the url before that willEnterForeground function is called?

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: NSURL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    myUrl = url.path

    return true
}
```

ViewController.swift

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "willEnterForeground:", name: UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)     
}


deinit {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: nil, object: nil)
}

func willEnterForeground(notification: NSNotification!) {

    methodUsingUrl()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your AppDelegate.swift should have a applicationDidBecomeActive() method. As per apple's documentation,

1. First `UIApplicationWillEnterForegroundNotification` notification is fired
2. Second, `AppDelegate:applicationDidEnterForeGroundNotification` is called
3. Third, `AppDelegate:applicationDidBecomeActiveGetsCalled` method is called
4. Fourth, `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification is fired

So for your scenario it makes sense to have the url gathered in either the `AppDelegate:applicationDidEnterForeGroundNotification` (or) `AppDelegate:applicationDidBecomeActiveGetsCalled` and have your ViewController.swift listen to the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification